# RoR: belongs_to_many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model of `Key Terms`that can belong to many `Articles` (1 Term can be used in many articles)? so a user can add key terms used and their explanations to articles for which they are used in? what would be the best way to establish this relationship?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a many-to-many relationship so you'll need to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)). And you'll need to create an interim table for `key_term_id` and `article_id` columns named `key_terms_articles` to maintain the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is what's referred to as a HABTM (has and belongs to many) relationship. There's a lot of stuff out there on the topic, and it can be a bit confusing at first to grasp. Try searching for "activerecord HABTM" or "Activerecord polymorph" and that should get you started.